# Using Material icon font with Angular component's encapsulation set to native

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2, shadow-dom, google-material-icons

I've used Material's icon font in the past with Angular 4+ projects as long as the component's encapsulation was emulated.  My current project only needs to support the latest versions of Chrome so I was going to try to set all the components to ViewEncapsulation.Native, which I understand uses the browser's native ShadowDOM.  However, I can't get the Material icon font to render in any of my components.

In my index.html file I have the font included like:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

And in my search component, with encapsulation set to native I have the following, which is not rendered using the icon font:

```
<md-icon>search</md-icon>
```

Has anyone been successful using an icon font with Angular's native encapsulation?

Comment: did you install material module ?

Comment: Can you show us your full code and any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, I have the Material module installed.  It works fine if I set the encapsulation to Emulated.  When you set it to Native, there are no errors, it just doesn't display the icons.  It displays the text "search" instead of the search icon.  I realize it's because of the native ShadowDOM, but how would you ever use Material Icons with Native encapsulation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you do. You can solve that, let's assume you have AppComponent which is your start component.

Add there:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

And then in AppComponent styles you can add styles which you want use in whole app.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same issue as you.
It seems that the CSS `@font-face` at-rule doesn't work yet with Shadow DOM and that's why material icons don't work with Native ViewEncapsulation.

There's a discussion on this matter here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336876 but I believe it has no solution for the moment.

As a workaround, may I suggest SVG-based icons instead of font-based, they should work just fine with Shadow DOM.